# How to upload video on twitpic/twitter programatically?

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I am new in Android. 
I was working for uploading Image/Video on Twitter. I used the twitpic for this purpose.
I first sent image to twitpic and then updated the status in twitter with url of the tweet.
Image is successfully loading as per my selection from gallery.

But I am stuck in uploading video on Twitter. As there is option of twitpic or twitvid for uploading video. But there is no such type of code or sdk given. So confused that how to do this, which classes has to be used.

I need a sample code for uploading video.

Answer (score 2):

Was stuck on this for a while myself as well (not a lot of examples around) and found a non-working example here on SO which I've managed to hammer into shape...

First you'll need the [twitvid Java API](http://twitvid.pbworks.com/w/page/22556292/Client%20Libraries)

1 download the jar file (I used twitvid-java 1.6.1)

2 put it in your "libs" folder

3 right-click on your project and go to "properties"

4 select "Java build path" and include the jar ("libraries" tab) and make sure it's built ("order and export" tab)

The code that follows assumes you've already made a token with the regular twitter4j methods:

```
private void postToTwitvid(String videoPath){

    AccessToken token = mTwitter.getAccessToken();

    Values values = new Values();
    values.setSession(new Session());
    TwitvidApi api = new TwitvidApi(values);
            api.setSecureUrlEnabled(false);

            Session session;
            try {
                session = api.authenticate(new TwitterAuthPack.Builder()
                .setConsumerKey(twitter_consumer_key)
                .setConsumerSecret(twitter_secret_key)
                .setOAuthToken(token.getToken())
                .setOAuthTokenSecret(token.getTokenSecret())
                .build());

                api.getValues().setSession(session);

                final UploadHelper helper = new UploadHelper(api);

                File file=new File(videoPath);
                TwitvidPost twitvidPost = new TwitvidPost.Builder()
                        .setFile(file).setChunkSize(10485760)
                        .setMessage("Twitvid test")
                        .setPostToTwitter(true)
                        .create();
                try {
                    if (helper.upload(twitvidPost))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(TwitterShare.this, "Posted on Twitter and Twitvid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(TwitterShare.this, "Post failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (ApiException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }



}
```

The token depends on how you've implemented the regular posting to twitter, just include yours.
Hope this helps!

PS: I had to force the UI thread to accept network connections to make this work

(My first answer! w00t!)

Comment: @user1504495 can you please send me twitvid java 1.6.1 sdk jar , because i am unable to find it anywhere. My email is smr.rahul@gmail.com . Thanks

Comment: ^ I can't find it anywhere too..

Comment: @RahulChauhan Do you have TwitVid SDK and is it still working ?

Comment: Me too unable to find that twitvid jar

Comment: Iam also unable to find that jar.Is there any other process. Please help me to share video to twitter.